# How can I correct for bad text encoding?

Tags: c#, sql, text, unicode, encoding

A little background.  We have terrible H1B-developed systems at work.  They're 50% SQL, 50% JS, 7 layers of Entity-like boilerplate in between, and in a constant state of emergency.  Some deployments take hours because they're pushing literally hundreds of DB scripts each time.

As a short term fix, I wrote a program to pump the script directory through a SqlCommand object.

The issue I'm having is that they're pasting incompatible codepages together.  The file looks like ascii but has some lines with unicode spaces.  When it's read in and executes, it errors out with garbage characters.  I had switched from autodetect to default encoding, which worked for about a day before they did something different and it started erroring out again.

SQL Management Studio flags these weird characters too but still manages to execute.  Is there anyway to force the text to be "normalized" somehow?  Or force it through whatever SSMS does?

Answer (score 1):

If the actual contents of these files is all meant to be in the 7-bit ASCII character set range then you can try reading the files as binary. You'll want to strip off any leading Unicode [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) you encounter and then skip any bytes which are 0 (which will be from files encoding as UTF16). Then feed it to a decoder and claim that it's ASCII or UTF-8.

If the character set is wider than the 7-bit ASCII range then I think all bets are off, and you need to solve the real problem, which sounds like it's a people problem rather than a technical one.

Comment: Well when I say ASCII it's probably more like Latin1 or Windows 1252.  When I wrote test scripts in Notepad or SSMS, autodetect worked.  I tried forcing all of the enumerated encodings with terrible results except for Default which MSDN says picks up the system default codepage.

I agree it's a people problem but we're long past solving that one.  They just don't have the skill set or the wherewithal to follow basic instructions.  Upper management doesn't have to put up with the consequences so there's no buy-in from them on anything.

Comment: No, it's a people problem. *push back*. You have tried to automate some of it but that's not feasible. Try to put an *actual cost* value in the time you're spending trying to fix this problem to them and ask if they want to invest this money in solving these problems or they'd rather you added business value.

Comment: @RyanKillian - hopefully, if you can get past that first step of "you're paying me to be here 40 hours a week and I'm spending 35 of them trying to tidy up after others", you can then (develop and/or enforce) standards. If the contracts are shit and basically say "we'll take whatever shit is delivered to us" then point out the problem. Basically, try to get someone involved who cares about the *bottom line*.

Comment: It's tangential to the question but A) this is government so cost of contractor foul-ups doesn't matter, B) I've had two CIOs marginalized for pushing back, and C) I _did_ develop standards nearly 18 months ago that were D) utterly ignored over 12 months of failed code reviews.  The last review I handed the project manager was two inches thick double-sided and that was just what I caught reading a million lines of spaghetti.  I'm just trying to cope while I look for better opportunities.  Your thoughts are appreciated though.